# How to connect with multiple Google Play Service API's along with Cast API

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast

I am using google play services with Google+ login so I need it to connect when the app starts but the Cast API requires a `CastDevice` to be selected before I can connect to google play services but when the app starts this is not possible.

this is how I have it set up currently

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .addApi(Plus.API)
                        .addApi(Drive.API)
                        .addApi(Cast.API,apiOptionsBuilder.build()) //not possible to be ready yet at this point
                        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                        .build();
    ....
}
```

If the user needs to select the cast device I cannot connect here but I need to connect when the activity starts for authentication

so how do you handle using the Cast API when you need other API's too? Do I need to have 2 instances of GoogleApiClient?

Comment: You can have different instances if you need to connect the other APIs earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I create a Google client without the cast initially, when I need to start casting I disconnect and create a new one. I doubt this is the best solution but it seems to work so far. Please share if you figure out something better.